# Find the maximum and minimum of $f(x,y)=xy-y+x-1$ on the set $x^2+y^2=2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

So I started the problem by first finding the critical points using the partial derivatives, which turns out that there is only 1 critical point at $(1,-1)$ where $f(1,-1)=0$

Then I know I must look at the outside, or when $g(x,y)=x^2+y^2=2$, and I believe I could use $\nabla f=\lambda*\nabla g$, and this leaves me with the following equations

$$y+1=2x\lambda$$

$$x-1=2y\lambda$$

$$x^2+y^2=1$$

And I am unable to solve this set of equations.  Could someone help me out on this step or see a flaw in an earlier step?

Comment: Isn't the constraint $x^2+y^2 =2$? Am I missing something?

Comment: @epsilon-delta yes that is the constraint, I realized I made a typo in the question where I put a 1 instead of a 2, but it's more than possible that I'm using the wrong approach for the problem

Comment: While I gather Lagrange multipliers are the technique you are supposed to practice, you could also turn this into a one-variable problem. On that constraint, $x=\sqrt{2}\cos t$ and $y=\sqrt{2}\sin t$ for some $t$.

Comment: @alex.jordan where I would plug these values into the original equation, do the first derivative and then solve for t when the derivative is equal to 0?

Comment: You'd be optimizing $f(t)=2\cos t\sin t-\sqrt{2}\sin t+\sqrt{2}\cos t -1$ using its first derivative.

Comment: @Anthony Did you try using $y^2 =2-x^2$ and cross-multiplying $\dfrac{y+1}{x-1}=\dfrac{x}{y}$ (assuming $y,\lambda>0, x \neq 1$). Or something similar with $x$ at the bottom?

Comment: @epsilon-delta no but I'm currently trying it that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide the first two equations to eliminate $\lambda$. After clearing denominators, you have a quadratic equation in $x$ and $y$. In combination with the constraint, eliminate $x$ (or $y$). And then you are almost done.